# Cambio de server error con office 365

Tags: c#, net, interop

tengo un proyecto en c# que hace uso de la librería de Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, este proyecto agrega imagenes y otros docx, dentro de un .dot(plantilla).

Donde esta el proyecto actualmente esta instalado el word 2019, si mal no recuerdo, y funciona bien. La empresa exige que se cambie a un servidor con el paquete de office 365, el cual hace login en word con las credenciales de windows. Al mover el proyecto al servidor nuevo da el siguiente error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

¿Alguno podrá ayudarme?

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: [Esta pregunta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466914/how-to-register-microsoft-office-interop-word-on-web-server) ayuda en algo?